# D3.js Arc Diagram - Tapered Ends

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have an arc diagram that is based on this [blocks example](http://bl.ocks.org/mayblue9/dcc49ef6e3888f37f755177c4a248f2c), and I'd like to taper the ends of the arc path so that they are hidden behind the circles (or at least aren't wider than the circles themselves).

I have two thoughts and I'm not sure how feasible either of them are: a) modify [d3.arc source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/main/src/arc.js) so that the resultant svg path has tapered ends, or b) instead of using d3.arc to generate the path, create my own cubic bezier function that takes in the x and y points of the source and target nodes and outputs a a curve that tapers to maybe half of its full width? Both of which I've never done before and would be floundering a bit trying to do.

Any tips, tricks, ideas, or general well wishes would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Re '...at least aren't wider than the circles themselves' - you can attempt to make `.outerRadius - .innerRadius` to be equal to twice the radius of the node circle ?

Comment: I mean, I can just change the scale of the arc diameter to be the same as the nodes' diameters (and have, for now, as a hopefully temporary solution). But that doesn't achieve the tapering affect, where the arcs can be thicker than the nodes but where the arc meets the nodes, they taper to be about the same size or smaller than the nodes, so they blend in. Sorry if there was confusion about what I was trying to say with that parenthetical.